# Преобразование аномальных "дат" в численных столбцах

Tags: python, pandas

Вопрос, обратный [заданному ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/982266/revisions): У меня есть данные, где в числовых столбцах по каким-то причинам лежат даты. Надо вылечить эти данные, чтобы вместо даты были числовые значения. Пример такого битого столбца можно скачать [тут](https://yadi.sk/i/1flkpChssjwXjg)

То есть, имею данные в столбце:

```
Предиктор
0.006232
0.0454
0.000213
0.00398
0.00003
01.июн
29.янв
```

Странные даты надо вернуть к числовому варианту без искажений информации.

UPD: Если нельзя вылечить, надо заменить NaN'ами, как это сделать? При обращении к ячейке выдается ошибка типа: `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 7232-06-01 00:00:00`

Comment: *в числовых столбцах по каким-то причинам лежат даты.* Кривой копипаст в Эксель.

Comment: Вроде как с КИПов пишется..

Comment: информация в этом столбце уже искажена в Excel файле. Примеры значений, прочитанных как строки, т.е. без преобразований: `["6999-04-01 00:00:00", "2597-04-01 00:00:00", "6574-03-01 00:00:00", "8341-02-01 00:00:00", ...]` Для того чтобы это исправить нужно понять по какому алгоритму эти даты были искажены

Comment: То есть просто вернуть в общий формат даже в самом экселе не получится?

Comment: @StepanSokol, попробуйте... Я попробовал преобразовать `9117-07-01 00:00:00` --> `2636138`, только непонятно что теперь делать с `2636138`

Comment: Данные, которые вы выложили - вы их уже получаете в таком формате или это после ваших преобразований?

Comment: Уже получил такие. Мне их как раз надо восстановить

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: https://ytikhonov.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/data-integer/

Comment: Модет проще будет запросить данные в другом формате (например CSV)?

Comment: Попробую, но скорее всего нет. Требовать с заказчика нормальные данные для нормальной работы, это сказка для детей ДСов)

Comment: ну если заказчик заинтересован в результате обработки данных... Кстати, это одна из задач Data Scientist - правильно объяснить заказчику необходимость получения максимально качественных данных (и в достаточном объеме). Иногда приходится "заманивать" - показывать интересные модели на основе тех данных, что клиент уже предоставил и пояснять, что с большим количеством данных можно построить более интересные и качественные модели.

Comment: Там ситуация, что контактное лицо заказчика - сам по себе ходит обивает пороги начальства, чтобы ему раз в сто лет выгрузили что-то.

Ладно, сделаю NaN'ы

Answer (score -1):

Открыть эксель. Правой кнопкой - формат ячеек. Поставить "число" с нужным форматом.

У меня всё получилось на образце данных.

Comment: нет уверенности, что получаемое число того же смысла, что и правильные значения. Такие исправления возвращают числа большие на несколько порядков

Comment: вопрос был что можно сделать с этим файлом) получите от заказчика сырые данные